# Swagger failing with 403 on Chrome & Firefox

Tags: apache, ssl, tomcat, https, swagger

I have application with below structure.

LoadBalancer (that resolves the https) <-> Apache Httpd Web Server <-> Apache Tomcat Servlet Container

I am exposing some APIs implemented in Jersey. And Swagger enabled to test easily.

Lately we have updated the tomcat instances from 7.x to 9.x version. (9.x has AJP commented out by default)

the weird behavior is; I try to test my authentication API through swagger. Results as below;

Chrome with a recent version, fails with 403. I can see the 403 in access logs of tomcat. But there is no log related to this in my app logs. So that I assume tomcat rejects the request because of some unwanted headers, props etc...

Firefox, 64.0.2 works just fine and is able to call the API without any issue. But if I upgrade the firefox to 72.0.2 version, then firefox stops working too and requests finished with 403 again.

IE works works fine :)

If I visit the swagger UI by the machine IP address and http (no https here, since https resolved in load balancer in normal scenario) all browsers works just fine.

I am assuming that there is an issue with chrome, https, ssl and web server's config that the request reached to my tomcat instance is kinda broken or mis-structured.

Some of the logs during the scenario can be seen here too.

```
10-Jun-2021 01:05:50.922 INFO [http-nio-8181-exec-38] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name [0x160x030x010x000xa30x010x000x000x9f0x030x010xb00x160xc3iC0xce0x9f/T0x8d0xb4Q_90xed0xdd0xe00xa3[0xf80xab0xc0&0x0b0xbe0x880xd40xa0E0x880xa20x830x000x00R0xc00x0a0xc00x140x0090x0080x000x880x000x870xc00x190x00:0x000x890xc00x090xc00x130x0030x0020x000x9a0x000x990x00E0x00D0xc00x180x0040x000x9b0x00F0xc00x070xc00x110xc00x160x000x180xc00x080xc00x120x000x160x000x130xc00x170x000x1b0x0050x000x840x00/0x000x960x00A0x000x070x000x050x000x040x000x0a0x000xff0x010x000x00$0x000x0b0x000x040x030x000x010x020x000x0a0x000x0c0x000x0a0x000x1d0x000x170x000x1e0x000x190x000x180x00#0x000x000x000x160x000x000x000x170x00...]. HTTP method names must be tokens
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:417)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:261)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
10-Jun-2021 01:06:05.482 INFO [http-nio-8181-exec-1] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target [/web/#/login]. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:498)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:261)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: I think this was related to the corporate restrictions on user's pc. An ooold IE had no problem during the testing.